# PHP keep track of the last x iterations

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have four variables: `$one_flag`, `$two_flag`, `$three_flag`, and `$four_flag`. I'm using them as flags inside a for loop because I want to keep track of the last four iterations.

```
$one_flag = 1;
$two_flag = 0;
$three_flag = 0;
$four_flag = 0;

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17, 27, 44, 45, 47, 49);

foreach ($a as $v) {
    if ($one_flag){
        $first_v = $v;
        $one_flag = 0;
        $two_flag = 1;
    }
    if ($two_flag){
        $second_v = $v;
        $two_flag = 0;
        $three_flag = 1;
    }
    if ($three_flag){
        $third_v = $v;
        $three_flag = 0;
        $four_flag = 1;
    }
    if ($four_flag){
        $fourth_v = $v;
        $four_flag = 0;
        $first_flag = 1;
    }
    if ($v == 45){
        # tricky part
        print "The last three v's were: " . $first_v . ", " . $second_v . ", " . $third_v . "\n";
    }
}
```

Right now it prints `The last three v's were 1, 1, 1` but it's supposed to print `The last three v's were 45, 44, 27`. Also, the problem with the code above is I need to know which flag is equal to `1` (what flag we're currently on) so that I can print the correct statement.

For example, when `$v == 45`, `$first_v` is suppose to equal to 27; `$second_v` is suppose to equal to 44; `$fourth_v` is suppose to equal to 17; and `third_v` is suppose equal to 45. I'd need to know `$three_flag` is equal to 1 in order to print out "The last three were $second_flag, $first_flag, $fourth_flag" in that order.

How can I get my loop to work? How do I keep track of the last four iterations?

EDIT: I misspoke. I actually want to print `The last three v's were 44, 27, 17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that this is a minimal example and that the real program is more complex. Otherwise, you could just get the length of the array and retrieve the last 3 elements based on it.

I'd change the approach as follow:

```
$f1 = -1;  // Last value read
$f2 = -1;  // second to last value
$f3 = -1;


$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17, 27, 44, 45, 47, 49);

foreach ($a as $v) {
    $f3 = $f2;
    $f2 = $f1;
    $f1 = $v;
    if ($v == 45){
        # tricky part
        print "The last three v's were: " . $f1 . ", " . $f2 . ", " . $f3 . "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm using -1 as an indicator that nothing was assigned to the variable. You should adapt this to your context if needed.

Comment: Nice use of cascading temporary variables. Reminds me of Duff's Device.

Comment: @Richard St-Cyr, I misspoke. see the EDIT on my OP. I'll see how to modify your solution to get the output I actually meant.

Comment: So, what are the conditions to decide what you want to print? The first 3 of the last 6 values?  What would be the result if the input array was:

`(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 15)? `

Comment: okay I got it. thanks. I like your solution. I agree with @bishop, it's an  elegant way of doing it. You're right. the problem in the actual program is much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

It'd help to know the problem you're trying to solve, but off-hand I'd use a circular array to keep track of the last four. (**Edited** per your revision):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17, 27, 44, 45, 47, 49);
$previous = array ();
$pCounter = 0;

foreach ($a as $i => $v) {
    if (45 === $v) {
        print_r(array_reverse($previous));
    }

    // track the last three using a circular array
    $previous[$pCounter] = $v;
    $pCounter = ($pCounter + 1) % 3;
}
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 44
    [1] => 27
    [2] => 17
)
```

[Try it online.](https://3v4l.org/fUtFl)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your if-statements.

```
//loop sets $v = 1
//this one is true due to initial parameters, execute
if ($one_flag){
    $first_v = $v; //$first_v = 1
    $one_flag = 0;
    $two_flag = 1; //$two_flag is now TRUE!!!
}
//$two_flag is true, execute immediately!
if ($two_flag){
    $second_v = $v; //$second_v = 1
    $two_flag = 0;
    $three_flag = 1;
}
```

Although in my reading, that should cause the print to give `The last three v's were 45, 45, 45`.  If you want to keep doing it like this, you will need to use `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17, 27, 44, 45, 47, 49);

$track = array();

$num = 3;

foreach ($a as $v){

    $track[] = $v;

    if (count($track) > $num){
        $track = array_slice($track, 1);
    }

    if ($v == 45){
        print_r(array_reverse($track));
    }

}
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 44
    [2] => 27
)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of **if** use **elseif**, it will serve your purpose, and change the variable name **$first_flag** to **$one_flag**.

```
    $one_flag = 1;
    $two_flag = 0;
    $three_flag = 0;
    $four_flag = 0;
    $probe_counter = 1;
     $first_v=0;
     $second_v=0;
     $third_v=0;$fourth_v=0;

    $a = array(1, 2, 3, 17, 27, 44, 45, 47, 49);

    foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
        if ($one_flag){
            $first_v = $val;
            $one_flag = 0;
            $two_flag = 1;
        }
        elseif ($two_flag){
            $second_v = $val;
            $two_flag = 0;
            $three_flag = 1;
        }
        elseif ($three_flag){
            $third_v = $val;
            $three_flag = 0;
            $four_flag = 1;
        }
        elseif ($four_flag){
            $fourth_v = $val;
            $four_flag = 0;
            $one_flag = 1;
        }

        if ($val == 45){
            # tricky part
            echo "The last three v's were: " . $first_v . ", " . $second_v . ", " . $third_v . "<br>";
        }
    }
```